# How was Suspicion (1941) supposed to end?

Tags: ending, suspicion

In Alfred Hitchcock's 1941 thriller *[Suspicion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspicion_(1941_film))*, starring Cary Grant and Joan Fontaine, the ending is jarringly congenial, everything becoming all happy in a total reversal from the dark and scary lead up. Hitchcock frequently complained that he had been forced to change the ending of the movie.

How was it supposed to end originally?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspicion_(1941_film)#Production

Comment: Also: http://www.writingwithhitchcock.com/suspicion2.html